zlib does not link properly when building OpenMPI 5.0.1 leading to runtime warning
I installed OpenMPI 5.0.1 on fresh installation of Ubuntu 24.04. All dependencies were installed via apt and should be in the standard locations. However, mpiexec gives the following runtime warning
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
PMIx was unable to find a usable compression library
on the system. We will therefore be unable to compress
large data streams. This may result in longer-than-normal
startup times and larger memory footprints. We will
continue, but strongly recommend installing zlib or
a comparable compression library for better user experience.

You can suppress this warning by adding "pcompress_base_silence_warning=1"
to your PMIx MCA default parameter file, or by adding
"PMIX_MCA_pcompress_base_silence_warning=1" to your environment.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

despite zlib being installed
pavel@pavel-Lenovo-ideapad-500-15ISK:~/Documents/temp$ dpkg -s zlib1g-dev
Package: zlib1g-dev
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Installed-Size: 1321
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: zlib
Version: 1:1.3.dfsg-3.1ubuntu2
Provides: libz-dev
Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.3.dfsg-3.1ubuntu2), libc6-dev | libc-dev
Conflicts: zlib1-dev
Description: compression library - development
 zlib is a library implementing the deflate compression method found
 in gzip and PKZIP.  This package includes the development support
 files.
Homepage: http://zlib.net/
Original-Maintainer: Mark Brown <broonie@debian.org>

pavel@pavel-Lenovo-ideapad-500-15ISK:~/Documents/temp$ dpkg -s zlib1g
Package: zlib1g
Status: install ok installed
Priority: required
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 162
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: zlib
Version: 1:1.3.dfsg-3.1ubuntu2
Provides: libz1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
Breaks: libxml2 (<< 2.7.6.dfsg-2), texlive-binaries (<< 2023.20230311.66589-8)
Conflicts: zlib1 (<= 1:1.0.4-7)
Description: compression library - runtime
 zlib is a library implementing the deflate compression method found
 in gzip and PKZIP.  This package includes the shared library.
Homepage: http://zlib.net/
Original-Maintainer: Mark Brown <broonie@debian.org>

and apparently detected by ./configure (see complete log here)
+++ Configuring MCA framework pcompress
checking for no configure components in framework pcompress... 
checking for m4 configure components in framework pcompress... zlib

--- MCA component pcompress:zlib (m4 configuration macro)
checking for MCA component pcompress:zlib compile mode... dso
checking for zlib pkg-config name... /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/zlib.pc
checking if zlib pkg-config module exists... yes
checking for zlib pkg-config cflags... 
checking for zlib pkg-config ldflags... 
checking for zlib pkg-config static ldflags... 
checking for zlib pkg-config libs... -lz 
checking for zlib pkg-config static libs... -lz 
checking for zlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for deflate... yes
checking will zlib support be built... yes
checking if MCA component pcompress:zlib can compile... yes

I unsuccessfully tried rebuilding after

making sure that the bundled pmix included in OpenMPI tarballs was used and not externally installed version, because apparently the later has priority even if it is older and possibly non compatible. I'm not sure how exactly pmix finds and uses zlib, but
ldd on /opt/openmpi-5.0.1/bin/mpirun, ./ompi/.libs/libmpi.so and /opt/openmpi-5.0.1/lib/libpmix.so.2 made any mention of it if it is any help.
adding --with-zlib=/usr --with-zlib-libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu (or just the former) and making sure $LDFLAGS, $CPPFLAGS, $LD_LIBRARY_PATH are set properly.

Output of ompi_info can be found here. I only need MPI for testing, non production purposes, so I can do without the missing features. However, I'm curious what could be causing this and bring attention to possible irregularity in the library. This post is tagged as fortran because I only tested (and care about) using mpifort.

did you try ldd on the libmpi.so rather than on mpirun?

@Gilles I edited the output in, but there is still no mention of zlib

actually, I've just realized that is PMIx for which there's a complain. Did you try ldd libpmix.so? My own openmpi install doesn't link explicitly libz, but libpmix does.

ldd /opt/openmpi-5.0.1/lib/libpmix.so.2 does not mention libz either
